# How can I debug an iPhone that is receiving phantom taps?

Tags: ios, iphone, touch, screen, hardware

I have a clock app that shows time and weather.

- When app launches I show clockViewController. If a user clicks on the the cloud looking button on it then I take them to weatherViewController
- On weatherViewController I present 4 day weather forecast and if they click on the arrow button it takes them back to clockViewController.
- I created both these buttons through drag and drop storyboard and added a Triggered Segues connection between the two view controllers. Pretty straight forward
- Everything works as expected and designed. (see these screenshots)

[image] 
[image]

Now here's the weird part, yesterday I got an email from a user saying this word to word ***"It takes 2-3minutes and them it switches to weather and then after some period back and then weather and it stays on weather . It works perfect on my 4S but always with bug on 5S?"***

How could this possibly happen? I thought about it being a hardware screen bug but how can it press buttons that are not laid out in the same pixel area on the screen?

I don't own a iPhone 5S so I cannot test that on a real device. I did however ran it in simulator (4-in 64 bit, Xcode 5, iOS 7) and for 30 minutes it remained on the clock page.

I kept telling this user that there is no way it could change on its own without someone actually touching the buttons but they keep insisting there is a bug in our software. Is this a problem with their hardware? Should they take their phone to Apple store? I am out of ideas ... short of telling them their is a ghost in their house that likes apple devices.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think there is anyway of us knowing. Maybe you call something that changes the view controller in the background. I don't think there is much that we can do to help you here.

Comment: @Popeye sorry but I don't change anything in the background. There are no IBActions connected to those UIButtons. I understand its one of those bugs that may not be fixed but I wanted to ask community if there is anything special with iphone 5s

Comment: Can you Ask the customer about in what condition of mobile he/she is running this app ? Condition means, if the Device was kept on charge during application usage ? I have run into this kind of Tocu Screen capacitance difference due to the Variable Charge Source. Probably a bad adapter .

Comment: @BalramTiwari they were using a docking station when they reported this issue. Coneybear suggested below the same thing that it might have something to do with charger / adapter. Since you are suggesting the same thing I told the user to remove their iphone from all power chords and then run our app and see what happens. I will reply back to the board as soon I get a feedback from the customer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen things like this before, weird phantom presses on the screen caused by faulty or cheap Chinese chargers and cords. It happened to my wife. Whenever she had her phone plugged in to a certain charger and cord we got off eBay, the voltage difference (I assume) caused the capacitors on the screen to go bezerk and tap in the wrong place when she did, or simply tap on it's own. It's a longshot, but asking the user to try another charger may help. And, as always:

[image]

Comment: @coneybeare they were using a docking station when they reported this issue. I told them to remove iphone from it, place it on a table and then run our app for 20-30 mins. Lets hope that fixes their phantom button clicks

Comment: user confirmed it was their charger. Thanks again.

Comment: Awesome! I am going to edit the title of this question so others may find a phantom click solution easier